# how to increment text box value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want increment `#hidtr` value in jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $('#hidtr').val(parseInt($('#hidtr').val()+1));     
    alert($('#hidtr').val());  
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
var val = $('#hidtr').val();
$('#hidtr').val((val*1)+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I will preferred below approach because don't need to use `$('#hidtr').val()` twice and you can also process the value as you like.

```
$('#hidtr').val(function(i, oldVal) {
  return parseInt(oldVal || 0, 10) + 1; // oldVal || 0 if initial is empty
});  
alert($('#hidtr').val());
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AuJv2/12/)**

---

If you don't want to use above approach then follow: **(@charlietfl mentioned)**

```
var hidtr = $('#hidtr'), // store the reference, not use multiple time
    val = parseInt( hidtr.val(), 10 ) || 0, // peek the value
    inc = val + 1;  // increment value

hidtr.val(inc); // set value
```

#### Note

**[`parseInt(value, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** accept two parameter, first one is value and second one is radix(for integer it will 10, for hex it will 16 and so on).

**[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** jquery accept a value as parameter to set and also a function (with two arguments index and old value).

Comment: Dude, the initial value is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#hidtr').val(parseInt($('#hidtr').val(),10)+1);
```

You had the brackets in the wrong place, also Radix is recomended, [see the docs for paraeInt here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: This is code execute but not value added.  `$('#hidtr').val()` is nan come

Comment: @panneerselvam What is the initial value ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in `ready` callback and make adjustments to brackets

```
$(function(){
   $('#hidtr').val(parseInt($('#hidtr').val(),10) || 0 +1);
    alert($('#hidtr').val());

});
```

See:  [jQuery Docs : How jQuery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) for explanation of why it needs to be wrapped

WHen using a selector more than once in a handler or function, it is better to cache it

```
$(function(){
    var $hidtr= $('#hidtr');
     var val=$hidtr.val();
   $hidtr.val(parseInt( val,10)  || 0 +1);
    alert( $hidtr.val());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Or another working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/AuJv2/5/ **OR** in case of initial empty input: http://jsfiddle.net/AuJv2/8/

Please note `parseInt($('#hidtr').val()+1)` should be `parseInt($('#hidtr').val())+1`

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
var num = parseInt($('#hidtr').val()) || 0;
$('#hidtr').val(parseInt(num)+1);
alert($('#hidtr').val());
```

​
**OR**

```
$('#hidtr').val(parseInt($('#hidtr').val())+1);
alert($('#hidtr').val());

​
```